# Best way to monitor multiple textboxes for changes

Tags: jquery, html, css, input, tabs

I have a form structured within a tabbed div (jQuery). Each div contains elements of the form specific to a section and there is a save button at the bottom of each tab section. I am trying to add a little warning icon next to the tab name (header) when the user has made changes to the form data but not saved it. Now I know I can check for .change on each of the textboxes and simply make the icon visible by toggling the display property. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of achieving the same functionality? Considering that all the form elements are within a div and have specific classes assigned to them, is there a way of checking if anything within the div has changed instead of listening for an event on every single form element?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
$("#divid > input").on("change", function(){
---
})
```

where "divid" is id of your div.